# iis 7.5 - allow only one domain name user to view site

Tags: c#, .net, iis, permissions, active-directory

I would like to have only 1 domain name user view my site (username1). 
So far I cant get this to work correctly. Either everyone has access or no one has access.

Webconfig:

```
 <authentication mode="Windows">
```

IIS setting:

```
Anonymous - disabled
Windows Authentication - enabled
```

sites folder permission settings:

```
IIS_USER (domain\iis_user) - no access
domain\username1 - read access
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"finds the first access rule that fits a particular user account" 
Try using the web.config.   And put domain\username1 allow first followed by `<deny users="*"/>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `identity impersonate` to true in your web.config.  That will pass the user information into the `WindowsIdentity` object (rather than just the `User` object).  The `WindowsIdentity` object is used in determining access to files and folders.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

More information can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/134ec8tc.aspx

Comment: If I add this, do I delete authentication mode=windows?

Comment: No. Windows authentication mode sets the `User` object based in your Windows login. You *could* take it out, since IIS defaults to Windows authentication, but it'd be better to leave it in.  This is an additional configuration to set the `WindowsIdentity` object to the user's login.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an authorization rule to allow or deny specific groups/people from within IIS. File permissions will still apply though. Also, just a side note, we also allow digest authentication. YMMV.

Here's a walkthrough on IIS Authorization Rules.

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authorization